# How to consume an observable in the HTML file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Now I have this list of videos on my side menu on my webapp. When any item on the list is clicked, an observable is fired and that helps change the "src" attribute of video tag. But it doesn't look like it's working.

Here's my html file:

```
 <div class="video-container video">
   <video width="400px" height="300px" controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer>
     <source [src]="src" type="video/mp4" /> Browser not supported   
   </video> 
 </div>
```

And here's my .ts file

```
src;
mySubs: Subscription<string>;

constructor(private vid: VideosService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.src = "...some default src";
    this.mySubs = this.vid.getVodSub().subscribe(index => {
      this.src = this.vid.videos[index].src;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.mySubs.unsubscribe();
  }
```

As you and I can guess, the video element takes the initial src attribute value set by me. But when the "src" property is changed in the .subscribe() method, the video src doesn't change.

I've also tried setting src attribute via calling a function, like src="getMySrc()", but it doesn't work too. 
How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Solved this problem by using the `src` attribute in the `video` element. `<video [src]="src" ..></video>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should keep as much logic outside of templates as you are able to :)

I think you should map your observable to another one which will give back `src` of the video.

Try something like:

```
src;
mySubs: Subscription<string>;
actualVideo: Observable<string>


constructor(private vid: VideosService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.actualVideo = this.vid.getVodSub().pipe(map(index => {
        return this.vid.videos[index].src;
    }));
}
```

Then use an async pipe in the template:

```
<source [src]="actualVideo | async" type="video/mp4" />
```

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe